# Is there a faster C++ Heap allocation/deallocation mechanism available than boost::object_pool?

Tags: c++, boost

This week I found out about boost::object_pool and was amazed that it was about 20-30% quicker than normal new & delete.

For testing I wrote a small C++ app that uses boost::chrono to time the different heap allocator/deallocator (shared_ptr). The functions itself do a simple loop of 60M iterations with a 'new' and 'delete'. Beneath the code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <memory>
using std::shared_ptr;

#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/chrono_io.hpp>
#include <boost/pool/object_pool.hpp>

#include <SSVUtils/SSVUtils.h>

#include "TestClass.h"

const long lTestRecursion = 60000000L;

void WithSmartPtrs()
{
    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Start time: " << startTime << std::endl;

    for (long i=0; i < lTestRecursion; ++i)
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<TestClass> spTC = boost::make_shared<TestClass>("Test input data!");  
    }

    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point endTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "End time: " << endTime << std::endl;

    boost::chrono::duration<double> d = endTime - startTime;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << d << std::endl;
}

void WithSTDSmartPtrs()
{
    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Start time: " << startTime << std::endl;

    for (long i=0; i < lTestRecursion; ++i)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<TestClass> spTC = std::make_shared<TestClass>("Test input data!");  
    }

    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point endTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "End time: " << endTime << std::endl;

    boost::chrono::duration<double> d = endTime - startTime;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << d << std::endl;
}

template<typename T> struct Deleter {
    void operator()(T *p)
    {
        delete p;
    }
};


void WithSmartPtrsUnique()
{
    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Start time: " << startTime << std::endl;

    for (long i=0; i < lTestRecursion; ++i)
    {
        boost::unique_ptr<TestClass, Deleter<TestClass> > spTC = boost::unique_ptr<TestClass, Deleter<TestClass> >(new TestClass("Test input data!"));  
    }

    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point endTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "End time: " << endTime << std::endl;

    boost::chrono::duration<double> d = endTime - startTime;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << d << std::endl;
}

void WithSmartPtrsNoMakeShared()
{
    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Start time: " << startTime << std::endl;

    for (long i=0; i < lTestRecursion; ++i)
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<TestClass> spTC = boost::shared_ptr<TestClass>( new TestClass("Test input data!"));   
    }

    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point endTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "End time: " << endTime << std::endl;

    boost::chrono::duration<double> d = endTime - startTime;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << d << std::endl;
}


void WithoutSmartPtrs()
{
    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Start time: " << startTime << std::endl;

    for (long i=0; i < lTestRecursion; ++i)
    {
        TestClass* pTC = new TestClass("Test input data!"); 
        delete pTC;
    }

    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point endTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "End time: " << endTime << std::endl;

    boost::chrono::duration<double> d = endTime - startTime;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << d << std::endl;
}

void WithObjectPool()
{
    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Start time: " << startTime << std::endl;

    {
        boost::object_pool<TestClass> pool;
        for (long i=0; i < lTestRecursion; ++i)
        {
            TestClass* pTC = pool.construct("Test input data!");    
            pool.destroy(pTC);
        }
    }

    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point endTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "End time: " << endTime << std::endl;

    boost::chrono::duration<double> d = endTime - startTime;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << d << std::endl;
}


void WithObjectPoolNoDestroy()
{
    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Start time: " << startTime << std::endl;

    //{
        boost::object_pool<TestClass> pool;
        for (long i=0; i < lTestRecursion; ++i)
        {
            TestClass* pTC = pool.construct("Test input data!");    
            //pool.destroy(pTC);
        }
    //}

    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point endTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "End time: " << endTime << std::endl;

    boost::chrono::duration<double> d = endTime - startTime;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << d << std::endl;
}



void WithSSVUtilsPreAllocDyn()
{
    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Start time: " << startTime << std::endl;

    {
        ssvu::PreAlloc::PreAllocDyn preAllocatorDyn(1024*1024);
        for (long i=0; i < lTestRecursion; ++i)
        {
            TestClass* pTC = preAllocatorDyn.create<TestClass>("Test input data!"); 
            preAllocatorDyn.destroy(pTC);
        }
    }

    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point endTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "End time: " << endTime << std::endl;

    boost::chrono::duration<double> d = endTime - startTime;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << d << std::endl;
}



void WithSSVUtilsPreAllocStatic()
{
    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Start time: " << startTime << std::endl;

    {
        ssvu::PreAlloc::PreAllocStatic<TestClass> preAllocatorStat(10);
        for (long i=0; i < lTestRecursion; ++i)
        {
            TestClass* pTC = preAllocatorStat.create<TestClass>("Test input data!");    
            preAllocatorStat.destroy(pTC);
        }
    }

    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point endTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "End time: " << endTime << std::endl;

    boost::chrono::duration<double> d = endTime - startTime;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << d << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << " With OUT smartptrs (new and delete): " << std::endl;
    WithoutSmartPtrs();


    std::cout << std::endl << " With smartptrs (boost::shared_ptr withOUT make_shared): " << std::endl;
    WithSmartPtrsNoMakeShared();

    std::cout << std::endl << " With smartptrs (boost::shared_ptr with make_shared): " << std::endl;
    WithSmartPtrs();

    std::cout << std::endl << " With STD smart_ptr (std::shared_ptr with make_shared): " << std::endl;
    WithSTDSmartPtrs();


    std::cout << std::endl << " With Object Pool (boost::object_pool<>): " << std::endl;
    WithObjectPool();

    std::cout << std::endl << " With Object Pool (boost::object_pool<>) but without destroy called!: " << std::endl;
    WithObjectPoolNoDestroy();


    std::cout << std::endl << " With SSVUtils PreAllocDyn(1024*1024)!: " << std::endl;
    WithSSVUtilsPreAllocDyn();


    std::cout << std::endl << " With SSVUtils PreAllocStatic(10)!: " << std::endl;
    WithSSVUtilsPreAllocStatic();


    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
On Ubuntu LTS 12.04 x64 with GNU C++ 4.6 and boost 1.49                                                                         


No smart ptrs (new/delete)                      5,08024     100     5,1387      100     5,1108      100     5,1099  100


With boost::shared_ptr No boost::make_shared                        7,36128 2,2810  145     7,34522 2,2065  143     7,28801 2,1772  143     7,3315  143

With boost::shared_ptr and boost::make_shared                       6,60351 1,5233  130     6,82849 1,6898  133     6,61059 1,4998  129     6,6809  131

With std::shared_ptr and std::make_shared                       6,07756 0,9973  120     5,93100 0,7923  115     5,9037  0,7929  116     5,9708  117


With boost::unique_ptr                      4,97147 -0,1088 100     5,0428  -0,0959 98      4,96625 -0,1445 97      4,9935  98


With boost::object_pool                     3,53291 -1,5473 70      3,60357 -1,5351 70      3,52986 -1,5809 69      3,5554  70

With boost::object_pool (Without calling Destroy)                       4,52430 -0,5559 89      4,51602 -0,6227 88      4,52137 -0,5894 88      4,5206  88
```

Results including SSVUtils PreAllocDyn on my MacBook Pro:
Compiled with:

```
  g++-mp-4.8 -I$BOOSTHOME/include -I$SSVUTILSHOME/include  -std=c++11 -O2 -L$BOOSTHOME/lib -lboost_system -lboost_chrono  -o smartptrtest smartptr.cpp

 With OUT smartptrs (new and delete): 
Start time: 1381596718412786000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
End time: 1381596731642044000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
Duration: 13.2293 seconds

 With smartptrs (boost::shared_ptr withOUT make_shared): 
Start time: 1381596731642108000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
End time: 1381596753651561000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
Duration: 22.0095 seconds

 With smartptrs (boost::shared_ptr with make_shared): 
Start time: 1381596753651611000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
End time: 1381596768909452000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
Duration: 15.2578 seconds

 With STD smart_ptr (std::shared_ptr with make_shared): 
Start time: 1381596768909496000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
End time: 1381596785500599000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
Duration: 16.5911 seconds

 With Object Pool (boost::object_pool<>): 
Start time: 1381596785500638000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
End time: 1381596793484515000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
Duration: 7.98388 seconds

 With Object Pool (boost::object_pool<>) but without destroy called!: 
Start time: 1381596793484551000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
End time: 1381596805774318000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
Duration: 12.2898 seconds

 With SSVUtils PreAllocDyn(1024*1024)!: 
Start time: 1381596815742696000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
End time: 1381596824173405000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
Duration: 8.43071 seconds

 With SSVUtils PreAllocStatic(10)!: 
Start time: 1381596824173448000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
End time: 1381596832034965000 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970
Duration: 7.86152 seconds
```

My question:
Are there, besides shared_ptr/unique_ptr/boost::object_pool more heap/allocation mechanisms that can be used for quick heap allocation/deallocation of large set of objects?

NOTE: I also have more results on other machines and Operating systems.

EDIT 1: Added SSVUtils PreAllocDyn Results
EDIT 4: Added my compiler commandline options and retested with SSVUtils PreAllocStatic(10)

Thanks

Comment: I have made some *undocumented* pools [here](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtils/blob/master/include/SSVUtils/PreAlloc/PreAlloc.h). You're probably looking for `PreAllocStatic`

Comment: It can probably made even faster if you can avoid individual destruction of the items. A common pattern in arena allocation is: allocate the arena, allocate individuals within the arena, deallocate the arena. However, formally not invoking an object's destructor is undefined behavior.

Comment: If you are comparing new/delete to boosts pool allocators have you checked they are thread safe? new/delete have to be thread safe but allocators don't and the boost docs don't say. Thread safety adds overhead.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Thanks for your SSVUtils reference I added it in above results.

Comment: @John5342 Thanks for the reminder. For the time being thread-safe is no issue. But it can become an issue in the future if we are going parallel.

Comment: @HenryRoeland: `PreAllocStatic<T>` should be much much faster (and appropriate) than `PreAllocDyn`, if `TestClass` is not polymorphic

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Sorry! Added PreAllocStatic<TestClass> to the tests. I'm now using 1MB of size. Is this the proper way to use it? See code. Thanks

Comment: @HenryRoeland: the `create`/`destroy` usage seems correct *(`create` should be able to deduce the type by itself, though)*. You're, however, constructing it incorrectly - constructor takes **the number of objects** you're going to pre-allocate, not the number of bytes. Example: if you wanted to pre-allocate space for 1000 objects, use `PreAllocStatic<T> preAlloc(1000);`. `PreAllocDyn`, on the other hand, requires a number of bytes. - Also: what command line parameters are you using to compile?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: I've retested with 10 object preallocations. See results. Above in the last result pane you'll find the compile options I use. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When I needed a fast new/delete mechanism I wrote it myself. Surly I had to compromise the requirements of "general dynamic allocation memory". This refinement gave me the ability to code exactly what I needed.
In nutshell -

- No need in arrays.
- Pre allocation is a must (like any heap, though).

The idea is very simple -

- pre-allocate a vector of the size of the object needed fast
  allocation/deallocation. e.g. `MyType preMyType[ 1000 ]`
- push the addresses of the preallocated objects into a stack.
- on new - pop an address
- on delete - push the returned address back to the stack.

I packed everything in a nice, simple to use framework that required little from the users.
It ended up in deriving from some class and declaring the initial size.
I can elaborate, including code sample, if you wish.

Comment: p.s got it running 2-4 times faster than the regular new/delete. The benchmark is an issue too...

Comment: Do you handle alignment if heterogeneous objects are allocated? Isn't it tedious?

Comment: @C.R No heterogeneous objects at the same stack. each class has its own operator new() and operator delete(). I have a stack per type.

Answer (score 0):

There's a wacky idea I once had by replacing an array of available slots with an integer. Check it out here:

https://code.google.com/p/cpppractice/source/browse/trunk/staticdelegate.hpp